# jest how to see all uncovered lines in CLI?

Tags: jestjs

I want to see uncovered lines which is hidden by "..." like: "... 03,104,107,111"

Any ideas?

```
  validation.ts                                                   |    76.92 |    82.61 |    53.33 |    76.19 |... 03,104,107,111 |
  worklistPage-util.ts                                            |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |... 63,68,69,70,73 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but not for the CLI.

I was able to check all uncovered lines by type `start coverage/lcov-report/index.html` which is created by istanbul.js in Window system

[image]